# Switched from MySQL to MySQLi requires the connection parameter

Tags: php, object-oriented, mysqli

I was working with really old PHP I learned years ago and decided to finally update it, so I changed all the `mysql` to `mysqli`. I noticed some MySQLi functions require you to pass the connection in the parameters. I ended doing something like this:

```
$con = getCon();
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE deleted=0");
```

`getCon()` is a return like `return Database::getConnection();` that uses the next class:

```
class Database {
    private static $db;
    private $connection;

    private function __construct() {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "...";
        $password = "...";
        $dbname = "...";

        $this->connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->connection->close();
    }

    public static function getConnection() {
        if(self::$db == null) {
            self::$db=new Database();
        }

        return self::$db->connection;
    }
}
```

I don't like adding the line `$con = getCon();` to the top of every function that uses `mysqli_query`. Is there a way to avoid this? (it is one extra line multiplied by every function that uses `mysqli` calls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use object-oriented style:

```
$con = getCon();
$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE deleted=0");
```

Refer to [Example #1](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-examples) on the PHP documentation for [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), as well as the [*Dual interface* quick start page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) for more information.

Looking back at the functions like deprecated [mysql_query()](http://php.net/mysql_query) it appears that it used the "*last link opened by [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/mysql_connect)*". If you really wanted to replicate that, you could define a wrapper function (potentially using [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)):

```
function mysqli_query_con($query, $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT)
    $con = getCon();
    return mysqli_query($con, $query, $resultmode);
}
```

Comment: hey sorry for all the trouble, I myself wasn't sure what I wanted, but I fixed this way https://pastebin.com/H9KxEANr

Comment: alright- cool. I guess `call_user_func()` isn't required, but it is usable